# GetWindowText() Doesn't Work For Greek

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I'm using this code to get a list of open windows:

```
Delegate Function EnumWindowDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Callback As EnumWindowDelegate = New EnumWindowDelegate(AddressOf EnumWindowProc)
Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    If IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then
        Dim TheLength As Integer = GetWindowTextLengthA(hWnd)
        Dim TheReturn(TheLength * 2) As Byte
        GetWindowText(hWnd, TheReturn, TheLength + 1)
        Dim TheText As String = ""
        For x = 0 To (TheLength - 1) * 2
            If TheReturn(x) <> 0 Then
                TheText &= Chr(TheReturn(x))
            End If
        Next
        If TheText <> "" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TheText & " (" & CStr(hWnd) & ")")
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal WNDENUMPROC As EnumWindowDelegate, ByVal lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowText Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal Txt As Byte(), ByVal Lng As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLengthA Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
```

Usage: `EnumWindows(Callback, IntPtr.Zero)`

It works **BUT** if a window with a greek title is opened ex. 'Μουσική' this code outputs 'œ¿ÅÃ¹º® '. As you can see something is wrong. Is there a way to fix this?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: You are using ANSI functions. Better to use p/invoke and specify Unicode.

Comment: I Tried it with Unicode too but then it returned questionmarks :(

Comment: You are doing it wrong then.

Comment: Could you send me a working version of this code ?

Comment: No. There are countless examples out there. Put some basic research in.

Comment: I tried many different things but none of them seem to work.

Comment: try GetWindowTextA instead,

Comment: Output from GetWindowTextA: ???s???

Comment: OK, try stuff at random then! Very hard to help somebody with that sort of approach.

Comment: I Found a weird way that seems to work! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why bother trying to understand. If it seems to work that's good enough. Crack on!

Comment: Well.... it doesn't work for child windows like a opened folder in Explorer e.t.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think i found the solution: Use GetWindowTextA instead of GetWindowText.

**@Trevor** suggested this in the comments of the question and I tried it but it didn't work. Somehow I managed to make it work.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help :). Here is the working code:

```
Delegate Function EnumWindowDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Callback As EnumWindowDelegate = New EnumWindowDelegate(AddressOf EnumWindowProc)
Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    If IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then
        Dim TheLength As Integer = GetWindowTextLengthA(hWnd)
        Dim TheReturn(TheLength * 2) As Byte
        GetWindowText(hWnd, TheReturn, TheLength + 1)
        Dim TheText As String = ""
        For x = 0 To (TheLength - 1) * 2
            If TheReturn(x) <> 0 Then
                TheText &= Chr(TheReturn(x))
            End If
        Next
        If Not TheText = "" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TheText & " (" & CStr(hWnd) & ")")
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal WNDENUMPROC As EnumWindowDelegate, ByVal lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal Txt As Byte(), ByVal Lng As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLengthA Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
```